# R remove groups with only NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, zoo

I have a dataframe similar to the one generated by the following structure:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- expand.grid(region   = c("USA", "EUR", "World"),
                  time     = c(2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020),
                  scenario = c("policy1", "policy2"),
                  variable = c("foo", "bar"))

df2 <- expand.grid(region   = c("USA", "EUR", "World"),
                  time     = seq(2000, 2020, 1),
                  scenario = c("policy1", "policy2"),
                  variable = c("foo", "bar"))

df2 <- filter(df2, !(time %in% c(2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020)))

df1$value <- rnorm(dim(df1)[1], 1.5, 1)
df1[df1 < 0] <- NA
df2$value <- NA

df1[df1$region == "World" & df1$variable == "foo", "value"] <- NA

df <- rbind(df1, df2)

rm(df1, df2)

df <- arrange(df, region, scenario, variable, time)
```

`df` contains two "types" of NA. For one combination of region and variable (World/foo), there is no data at all. For all other combinations, we have NAs for all years except 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020.

I need a filter that removes the combinations of regions and variable that do only contain NAs, but keeps those combinations that only contain a few NAs. Background is that I want to apply a linear interpolation to compute the missing values for the latter by combining `dplyr` and functionality from the `zoo`-package (for the interpolation) using something like this:

```
df <- group_by(df, region, scenario, variable, time) %>%
      mutate(value = zoo::na.approx(value)) %>% ungroup()
```

The group containing only NAs leads to `na.approx` returning an error since it cannot function only with NAs.

Answer (score 10):

To keep only combinations of `region` and `variable` that have at least 1 non-NA entry in `value` you can use:

```
df %>% group_by(region, variable) %>% filter(any(!is.na(value)))
```

Or equivalently:

```
df %>% group_by(region, variable) %>% filter(!all(is.na(value)))
```

And with data.table you could use:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(any(!is.na(value))) .SD, by = .(region, variable)]
```

An approach in base R could be:

```
df_split <- split(df, interaction(df$region, df$scenario, df$variable))
do.call(rbind.data.frame, df_split[sapply(df_split, function(x) any(!is.na(x$value)))])
```

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me towards it: ``df <- group_by(df, region, scenario, variable) %>% filter(!all(is.na(value)))`` did the trick. The additional grouping by scenario is important since otherwise all values for ``World`` will be removed.

Comment: Another base analogue: `with(df, df[ !ave(value, region, scenario, variable, FUN = function(x) all(is.na(x))), ])`